# Unscaling Principal Components Regression Coefficients to Match Linear Regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, pca, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I am working with a dataset.  We can call it `dataset`.

```
           portfolio       USSW2      USSW5     USSW10     USSW30
2017-10-31    -0.430     0.01510     0.0171     0.0055    -0.0023
...
```

Each of the values are absolute changes in daily value.  Since the original values are quoted in percentages, the values in this dataset represent daily change in percentage quoted.  So, a "portfolio" value of 1.0 could correspond to a true portfolio value change of 3.0% to 4.0%.

Let's assume the covariates are highly correlated.  I mean very highly correlated, as such:

```
       USSW2   USSW5   USSW10   USSW30
USSW2   1.00                   
USSW5   0.94    1.00             
USSW10  0.85    0.97     1.00       
USSW30  0.76    0.90     0.97     1.00
```

Yes, I realize there is a multicollinearity problem.  Let's ignore that for the moment.
I can run a regression on this data (using R) using a standard `lm()` command.

```
> test.reg1 <- lm(portfolio~. , data=dataset)

Call:
lm(formula = portfolio ~ ., data = aligned.port)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.99416 -0.08703 -0.01272  0.09911  1.80345 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)         -0.001107   0.022498  -0.049  0.96080   
USSW2                0.542981   3.171097   0.171  0.86424   
USSW5              -13.689734   5.008679  -2.733  0.00692 **
USSW10               6.976394   5.817408   1.199  0.23207   
USSW30               7.052272   3.460557   2.038  0.04307 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2882 on 174 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2887,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2724 
F-statistic: 17.66 on 4 and 174 DF,  p-value: 3.505e-12
```

I can interpret the Beta values (estimates) of the regression as such:

- When USSW2 increases by 1, portfolio increases by 0.542981
- When USSW5 increases by 1, portfolio decreases by -13.689734
- ...

If I am correct in this, then the interpretation of the result is really simple and useful to me.  I can understand how one variable (or multiple variables) affect the portfolio variable in my regression.

I can also split the dataset, 80:20, into training and testing.  This way, I can test for MSEP (mean squared error of prediction) of my standard linear regression.

```
# set up training and testing datasets
> range.train <- 1:round(0.8*nrow(dataset))
> train.data <- dataset[range.train,]
> test.data <- dataset[-range.train,]

# fit model and run prediction
> fit.train1 <- lm(portfolio ~., data=train.data)
> predictions1 <- predict(fit.train1, test.data)
> fit1.ActPred <- xts(cbind(actuals=test.data$portfolio, predicteds=predictions1))
> mse1 <- mean((fit1.ActPred$portfolio - fit1.ActPred$predicteds)^2)

&&&&& Mean Squared Error of Prediction, Regression =  0.2749278
```

Everything up to this point is standard, except for the fact that my model is not real great.  Please remember this is a toy version of the real dataset I am working with, so using the methods I am using really do make sense.

Next, I run Principal Component Regression (PCR) on the same dataset.  There is a very nice R package that does this for me (including rescaling).  In my understanding, PCR is doing the following:

1. Running PCA on my covariates to determine loadings on PCs.
2. Running regression using PCs (not input variables) as new covariates.

This sounds pretty good!  Maybe I will get a better result if I effectively group my covariates prior to regressing.  I give it a try, holding my the number of components steady at 3:

```
> library(pls)
> pcr.a <- pcr(portfolio ~., data=dataset, 
               scale=TRUE, validation="CV", ncomp=3, jackknife=TRUE)
> print(summary(pcr.a))

Data:   X dimension: 179 4 
        Y dimension: 179 1
Fit method: svdpc
Number of components considered: 3

VALIDATION: RMSEP
Cross-validated using 10 random segments.
       (Intercept)  1 comps  2 comps  3 comps
CV          0.3388   0.3443   0.3050   0.3073
adjCV       0.3388   0.3436   0.3043   0.3061

TRAINING: % variance explained
           1 comps  2 comps  3 comps
X           92.268    99.21    99.86
portfolio    2.804    24.87    28.25
```

From this, I can get the percentage of variance explained by my target 3 PCs (28.25%), which is comparable to my adjusted R-squared value from my standard regression (27.24%).  If I run the train/test protocol using this method to predict "future" values, I can get the MSEP for PCR as well.  `MSEP(PCR) = 0.2578109`, while `MSEP(reg) = 0.2749278`.  This is also slightly better.

Now I want to get beta values in the same way I did before.  I use a built-in function which is able to extract the same beta value structure from the PCR routine:

```
> options(warn=-1);  print(jack.test(pcr.a));  options(warn=0)

Response portfolio (3 comps):
                     Estimate Std. Error Df t value Pr(>|t|)  
USSW2              -0.0262841  0.1456076  9 -0.1805  0.86075  
USSW5              -0.2910241  0.1986047  9 -1.4653  0.17687  
USSW10             -0.0033343  0.1071678  9 -0.0311  0.97586  
USSW30              0.3935101  0.1300165  9  3.0266  0.01432 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Since the values are scaled in the method, I can't interpret the values in the same way as linear regression.

How can I transform my beta estimates in this PCR routine so that they can be understood in the same way as the linear regression?